# Django has no response to anchor tag

Tags: django

```
 <a  href="#test" data-toggle="tab">test</a>

 ...

 <div class="tab-pane " id="test">
    <table>
    ...
    </table>
 </div>
```

When #test anchor is clicked, the behavior should be logged in the server. So in urls.py, I defined something like this

```
url(r'#test$', views.log())
or 
url(r'.*#test$', views.log())
```

But it seems it doesn't work. 
I have to use anchor here, because I don't want to refresh the page.
Any ideas?

Comment: I think that what you are trying to Todo can't be done this way. Using ids in anchors don't refresh the page as you said and so there is no request and no way for Django to receive the _message_ as URLs are triggered by requests.

Comment: An achor is not an URL. If you go to `#foo`, then you do *not* make a call to the server, the browser moves in the page to the anchor. You thu swill need some JavaScript that makes an AJAX call to make a request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some JavaScript that takes links with a `href` attribute starting with `#` and makes a request to `https://localhost:8000/<whatever was after the hash sign>` whenever the links are clicked. It's not robust and it needs to be modified for your circumstances, but maybe it works as a starting point.

```js
var hashLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]');
var i;

function hashLinkClicked(event) {
    var hash, url, request;
    // You probably want to allow default link behaviour here
    event.preventDefault();
    hash = this.hash;
    // Cut hash character out of URL
    url = 'http:/localhost:8000/' + hash.slice(1);
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function () { /* Handle response here */ };
    request.open('GET', url);
    request.send();
}

for (i = 0; i < hashLinks.length; i++) {
    hashLinks[i].addEventListener('click', hashLinkClicked);
}
```